# JSTL C taglib on Tomcat 5.0

Tags: tomcat, jstl

I'm using the jstl c taglib in a web application which I deployed on Tomcat 6.0.26. I need to run this web application on Tomcat 5.0.28... the problem is that the jstl tags are not being interpreted. For example, I'm getting `${status.errorMessage}` written on my login page whereas this should be empty unless the password entered is wrong.

The JSTL library is inside my web app. It's there the lib folder....

What could be wrong plz?
Thanks,
Krt_Malta

Answer (score 0):

Ok found it.

I put this in my web.xml:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd" version="2.4">
```

Hope someone finds it handy.
Krt_Malta